# what are the drawbacks of implementing sort() of arrays as static and composing it with comparable at run time?

Tags: java, design-patterns

We know that we should favor composition over inheritance, right? Well, the implementers of the
`sort()` template method decided not to use inheritance and instead to implement `sort()` as a static
method that is composed with a Comparable at runtime.

- How is this better?
- How is it worse?
- How would you approach this problem?
- Do Java arrays make this particularly tricky?

Comment: Better than what, specifically?  How would you implement this with inheritance?

Comment: As of my thinking, question may be asking  "why is it better to use composition to implement sort() template method?"

Comment: May be we can make "Arrays" class abstract and marking mergeSort() (in sort() template method) as abstract. But then arrays cannot be instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

There are always design debates about adding functionality to a Class, or to an associated utility class.  Like you, I prefer the former, but some argue that this can make a class "too big".   I would put sort() in Collection, not in Collections, but Sun decided otherwise.

Also, an array is, in some ways, not treated as a "real" class, so there might have been implementation issues.

**Clarification added**

You would still want a static sort() utility method in Collections (or in AbstractCollection) so that the canned implementations, and any user-defined implementations, could easily sort themselves.  So, `MyGoofyCollection.sort()` could just call `Collections.sort(this);`  However, the idiom I would prefer for usage is to call `myCollection.sort()`, instead of the current `Collections.sort(myCollection)`.

Note that this also allows a specific implementation to provide their own, optimized implementation of sort().  For example, if I have a AlwaysSortedList, it's implementation of sort() is to do nothing.

However, this is all fairly useless discussion, as Java has already implemented it their way and it's unlikely to change...  Maybe in Java 9 or 10?

Comment: For the record, `List.sort(Comparator)` is introduced in Java 8. http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort%28java.util.Comparator%29

Comment: Good!  I haven't looked at Java 8 much (obviously).

Comment: But how we can comment about how it is worse using composition over inheritance in this case?